# What does R stand for in Von Neumann Architecture?

Tags: computer-architecture

I would like some examples of modern day equipment that would equate with the 'R' in Von Neumann architecture.

I am referring to Section 2.6 on page 3 of the PDF version of the ["First Draft of a Report on the EDVAC"](http://qss.stanford.edu/~godfrey/vonNeumann/vnedvac.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The device must be endowed with the ability to maintain the input and output (sensory and motor) contact with some specific medium of this type (cf. 1.2): That medium will be called the outside recording medium of the device: R. Now we have:

*R* is any device which humans interact with to provide machine input or for the machine to provide human readable output.

In section 1.2, your pdf notes the EDVAC could use:

> Punched into a system of punchcards or on teletype tape, magnetically impressed on steel tape or wire, photographically impressed on motion picture film, wired into one or more fixed or exchangeable plugboards—this list being by no means necessarily complete.

In modern computing we have monitors, printers, keyboards, mice, Kinect, and numerous other ways of sensing input or providing output.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot. I don't know why I am so confused about this. Probably because I moved countries and still getting used to the time difference.